# How can I get rid of all the extra numbers in this return date from react-date-picker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am trying to just show the Month and Day but I am getting "Tue Oct 22 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)". When using "react-date-picker", how can I just have it return ex: "Tue Oct 22 2019" without resorting to truncating the text?

```
<DatePicker
  name="date"
  onChange={this.handleDate}
  value={this.state.date}
  format="M-dd"
/>
```

Comment: which datepicker are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you're looking for - `toLocaleDateString()`

```js
const today = new Date();

console.log(today); // "2019-10-17T04:38:49.459Z"

console.log(today.toLocaleDateString("en-US")); // 10/17/2019
```

` - Returns the second (0-59).

Additionally, JavaScript Date has several methods allowing you to extract its parts:

`getFullYear()` - Returns the 4-digit year
`getMonth()` - Returns a zero-based integer (0-11) representing the month of the year.
`getDate()` - Returns the day of the month (1-31).
`getDay()` - Returns the day of the week (0-6). 0 is Sunday, 6 is Saturday.
`getHours()` - Returns the hour of the day (0-23).
`getMinutes()` - Returns the minute (0-59).`

*There are a few more, but these are the important ones.*

May I also suggest exploring the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library.